# Is the free Mathematica Trial Version a full version?

Tags: installation

There is a [trial](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/) version of Mathematica in the Wolfram website, which can be downloaded for free with a license valid for 15 days. Is this version of Mathematica a "full version"? That is, during these 15 days, will I be able to use all of Mathematica functionality? Or are there some limitations?

Comment: I had recently downloaded a trial version for my daughter and it was showing "Home Edition" if I remember correctly. Thus the trial version should have the (minor) restrictions of the "Home Edition":  4 Kernels for evaluation (instead of 8), 1 Frontend (instead of 2) and less calls to Wolfram Alpha. (I refer to the [German reseller information for the Home Edition](http://software.additive-net.de/de/produkte/wolfram/lizenzierung/mathematica-varianten))

Comment: For any official info, you should directly contact WRI or the reseller.

Comment: Last time I tried a trial version, it could not `Export` figures.  I do not know if this restriction is still in place, it might not be.  People have been complaining that they could not evaluate if Mathematica is good for making figures ...  So as Yves says, best to ask WRI directly.  http://www.wolfram.com/support/

Comment: In the trial version I have tested (version 8, I think), I couldn't export anything, not only figures.

Comment: Why the close vote? Please leave a comment. If this isn't on topic here, explain why. It is a question about Mathematica.

Comment: @becko This question is much more appropriate by Wolfram technical support or sales personnel. Whatever information we can provide is anecdotal and perhaps imprecise, and may not be as accurate or trustworthy as whatever they can say. One of the reasons to close questions is specifically because the question would be more appropriate for Wolfram support.

Comment: I would keep this question open because the question is on topic and legitimate and the only issue there is may be uncertainty in any answer not coming directly from WRI. But why not including maybe an official answer from WRI so one would have it for further reference? I for once noted that I rather search on SE than on the WRI pages for some reason...

Comment: @MarcoB I think that reasoning could apply to all of Mathematica.SE. Any question here could be answered with higher authority by WRI. But I don't think that is the point. The point of a community like this is that we can all learn from our shared experience, which is much more efficient than if we all relied on direct replies from WRI.

Comment: @becko I disagree. MMA.SE is about *applications* of the Wolfram language to specific problems. Wolfram will not provide such free consulting services, nor would it necessarily be the best source for such solutions: users continuously extend the capabilities of a language beyond its original design. However, Wolfram *is* the ultimate source for info on *Mathematica* as a commercial product, which is what you are after. While implementing an algorithm in FORTRAN, you might ask for help on a forum; if you wanted info on licenses for the Intel FORTRAN compiler, you'd best ask Intel directly.

Comment: @becko Perhaps more to the point as well, **questions on licensing are explicitly off-topic** in this forum. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: - Questions on Wolfram Alpha; - **Questions on licensing**, specific support arrangements, product availability and pre-release versions of Mathematica — please contact Wolfram Support at support@wolfram.com. Questions about the site itself — please ask on the meta site instead."

Comment: @gwr "But why not including maybe an official answer from WRI so one would have it for further reference? " --> Because at some point in the future the answer would inevitably become obsolete and therefore generate confusion, which would make it worse than useless.

Comment: @MarcoB "Because at some point in the future the answer would inevitably become obsolete and therefore generate confusion, which would make it worse than useless" -> Well that would indeed hold for any Change in Version maybe and concerns a lot of threads here on SE? Also one anybody can see the date of the information and can judge for himself.

Comment: I would also add that the question touches *performance issues* (eg. the number of kernels in an edition). So maybe we should also not ask about differences in Version between Mac OS and Windows?